# Gson throwing JSON Error “java.lang.IllegalStateException"

Tags: java, android, gson, parcelable, illegalstateexception

I have this model: `Map<MyObjectA, Set<MyObjectB>>` where `MyObjectA` is a complex object but `MyObjectB` it's not. Both are `Parcelable`.

Here's an example:

```
{
    "my.package.models.MyObjectA@5415636": [{
        "member1": "val",
        "member2": "val",
        "member2": "val",
        ...
    }]
}
```

This operation works:

```
private boolean putObject(String key, Object object) {
    ...
    return mPreferences.edit().putString(key, mGson.toJson(object)).commit();
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
type = new TypeToken<Map<MyObjectA, Set<MyObjectB>>>() {}.getType());
private <T> T getObject(String key, Type t) {
    ...
    return mGson.fromJson(mPreferences.getString(key, null), type);
}
```

throwing:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 3 path $.

I've run debug mode and used a break point at `line 810` in `Gson.java`:

```
...
try {
      reader.peek();
      isEmpty = false;
      TypeToken<T> typeToken = (TypeToken<T>) TypeToken.get(typeOfT);
      TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = getAdapter(typeToken);
      T object = typeAdapter.read(reader);
      return object;
    } catch (EOFException e) {...}
}
```

`typeToken` and `typeAdapter` are correct but `typeAdapter.read(reader);` will fail...
`typeToken = java.util.LinkedHashMap<MyObjectA, java.util.HashSet<MyObjectB>>`
`typeAdapter class com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter`

What am I missing?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
public class MyObjectA {
    private List<MyObjectB> list;
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private int one;
    private int two;
...
}

public class MyObjectB {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;
...
}
```

Comment: What are MyObjectA and MyObjectB? It's hard to tell what you expect the result of the parsing to be.

Comment: So, for your example JSON, what are you expecting the parsed result to look like?  Your key in that example looks like a toString() rendering of some object, which will probably be useless when parsed.

Comment: Damn I think I know what it is, I can't have a Complex object as a Key right? I've run into this problem once long time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986269/gson-map-key-pair-to-json I've remembered now :/

Comment: Right, it's best to have strings as keys, so HashMap<String, OtherType> should work OK.